# How to solve this integral with separation of variables?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have this following differential equation

$$
\left(\frac{dx}{d\gamma} \right)^{2} = \frac{M^2E^2}{L^2}-x^2 (1-2x) \,\, ,
$$

where the parameters $M,E,L \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ are all constants, and the variable $x(\gamma), \gamma \in \mathbb{R}$. Performing a separation of variables I get,

$$
\int d\gamma = \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\frac{M^2E^2}{L^2}-x^2 (1-2x)}} \,\, ,
$$
where the left hand side of the equation is straightforward to get $\gamma + C$, but how could I solve the right hand side of this equation?

Comment: $x$ is a function of $\gamma$?

Comment: @Masacroso yes, I’ll update the question!

Comment: Wolfram Mathematica doesnt give an explicit primitive to the integral in the RHS.

Comment: @Masacroso No, it doesn’t.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int d\gamma = \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{C^2-x^2 (1-2x)}} \quad;\quad C^2=\frac{M^2E^2}{L^2}$$

Well, I am not so smart than the Great Wolfram Mathematica, but I will do my best.

One know how to solve the cubic equation :$\quad C^2-r^2(1-2r)=0\quad$ for $r$.

I let you find the roots $r_1$ , $r_2$ , $r_3$. Now, consider that they are known functions of $C$. As a consequence, we obtain :

$$C^2-x^2 (1-2x)=2(x-r_1)(x-r_2)(x-r_3)$$
$$\int d\gamma = \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{2(x-r_1)(x-r_2)(x-r_3) }} $$

$$\gamma = -\sqrt2\:\:F\left(X\:|\: m\right)+\text{constant, }$$
$F(X\:|\:m)$ is the elliptic integral of the first kind, with $\begin{cases}
X=\sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{r_2-r_1}{x-r_1}} \right) \\ m=\frac{r_1-r_3}{r_1-r_2} \end{cases}$

Thanks to WolframAlpha :
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2Fsqrt(2(x-a)(x-b)(x-c))&x=0&y=0

$$ F\left(X\:|\: m\right)= -\frac{\gamma}{\sqrt2}+c$$
The inverse function is the Jacobi amplitude function :
$$X=\text{am}\left(-\frac{\gamma}{\sqrt2}+c\:\bigg|\: m\right)$$
$$x(\gamma)=r_1+\frac{r_2-r_1}{\sin^2\left(\text{am}\left(-\frac{\gamma}{\sqrt2}+c\:\bigg|\: \frac{r_1-r_3}{r_1-r_2}\right)\right)}$$

Comment: But, when I get my answer I cannot invert the function, I'm interested in $x(\gamma)$ instead of $\gamma (x)$.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Jacobi elliptic functions ? See the addition to my previous answer.

Comment: Your roots $r_{1}, r_{2},r_{3}$ are ordered in ascend order? @JJacquelin

Comment: I didn't consider the order of the roots, without careful study of the problem. In fact, my answer is only a quick hint, nothing more.

Comment: If I consider $C^2=1/27$, how the solution would look like? In this way the polynomial $2(x +1/6)(x - 1/3)^2$ has one root with algebric multiplicity equals to two... I'm really not familiar with this treatment. If you have some reference to me I would be thankful.

Comment: One have to be aware that, for some particular values of the parameters, the special functions reduces to simpler functions, eventually to elementary functions. The above solution is for the general case. The example with $C^2=1/27$ is a particular case, with particular roots. In such a case, better come back to the first integral which is directly integrable in term of elementary functions : $$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{27}-x^2 (1-2x)}}=-2\tanh^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2x+\frac13}\right)$$